# Pyspark - strange behaviour of the method DataFrame.summary() with date columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

`DataFrame.summary()` seems to work incorrectly with date columns. For example, the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
data = {"namecol": ["foo", "bar"], 
        "datecol": ["01-JAN-17", "02-MAY-19"],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# (create the spark object)

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
print(df.summary("count").collect()[0].asDict())
```

yields

> {'summary': 'count', 'namecol': '2', 'datecol': '2'}

However, if I cast `datecol` with `to_date()` then `summary("count")` doesn't work properly:

```
datecol = F.to_date(F.col("datecol"), "dd-MMM-yy")
df2 = df.withColumn("datecol",datecol)
print(df2.summary("count").collect()[0].asDict())
```

gives me the following output:

> {'summary': 'count', 'namecol': '2'}

This is either a bug or I am misunderstanding something fundamental about `DataFrame.summary()`. In any case, it looks like it cannot find the count for columns with date type.

Is there an alternative to using `DataFrame.summary("count")`? I have quite a lot of columns un a dataframe and I'm looking for a fast way to get the number of non-`null` rows in each column.

Comment: `summary` and `describe` only compute statistics for numeric or string columns

Comment: I see. Is there a similar function that can be applied to the entire dataframe or do I have to count the non-`null` values separately for each column?